# Is there a way to find the ignored JUnit Test with the most lines of code in a large codebase?

Tags: java, junit, static-analysis

This is a static analysis question. It might be possible to write an AST parser with the ANTLR plugin in Checkstyle - or the backend to Findbugs. I'm looking for a pre-existing solution.

We have a weekly meeting of our developers in which we talk about issues of the day. Part of this is looking at the code quality reports in Sonar.

We have a number of ignored JUnit tests we're working through - and I'd like to rank them by size (lines of code in the JUnit test method).

My question is: **Is there a way to find the ignored JUnit Test with the most lines of code in a large codebase?**

Here is an example of an ignored method in a JUnit test:

```
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.junit.Ignore;
  import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

  public class TestJunit {

     String message = "Robert";   
     MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil(message);

     @Ignore
     @Test
     public void testPrintMessage() {
        System.out.println("Inside testPrintMessage()");
        message = "Robert";
        assertEquals(message,messageUtil.printMessage());
     }

     @Test
     public void testSalutationMessage() {
        System.out.println("Inside testSalutationMessage()");
        message = "Hi!" + "Robert";
        assertEquals(message,messageUtil.salutationMessage());
     }

  }
```

Here is the [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html) for the `@Ignored` annotation.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_ignore_test.htm

**Assumptions**:

- Simple line-count - counting whitespace is fine. (If a more sophisticated line-count is available that's great - but all I want is a consistent baseline for comparison).
- @Ignored can apply to classes and methods - ideally I want both, but this question was originally about ignored methods - so I'll stick with that.

Comment: You can't just measure the size of the junit files using something like unix wc?

Comment: I don't want the file - I want the method - only those that are ignored.

Comment: OK, define "ignored".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've updated the question.

Comment: So what you mean by "ignored" is "a method with @Ignored attribute"? Or also with "@Test attribute"?  Iassume further that you don't want to know just the largest one... would you want a list of them sorted by size?  Do you want actual line count [do blanks lines in the middle count?] or do you want "total mass"  [something like counting the tokens, ignoring lines]?

Comment: @hawkeye - using reflection on the test classes for annotation `@Ignored` ?

Comment: @nullpointer:  reflection can you get line count for a method?

Comment: @IraBaxter  *I don't want the file - I want the method - only those that are ignored*  followed the comment while suggesting

Comment: @nullpointer: he wants the *size* of the method, too.

Comment: ... @Ignored can be applied to a class.  Do you want the largest method in that class, or do you want to report the class and its size, too?

Comment: I want both - but I'll start with methods - as that is more common and the harder use-case.

Comment: ... and what if a test method A calls another method B?  Do you want the total size of all methods A+B? (after all, this is the size of the test code) or just A?

Comment: Just method A - I'd be interested to know if any line-counting tools did that - that would be impressive.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the maven surefire reports plugin to collect all the test reports, actually the ignored tested are collected by default, just like the below screenshots show, and you can go through all the ignored tests details.

[image]

[image]